# How to upgrarde module in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

Can someone explain to me how to upgrade taxonomies-module? Im currently running version 1.4 of taxonomy-module and I see that the current version is 1.4.2.

Must i disable the module in backend and clone the new source for contrib.taxonomies and rebuild in VS?

I am running 1.6 of Orchard.

Comment: It would be great if you'd mark my answer as answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unless stated otherwise in a module's release notes you can simply overwrite the old source with the new (or over-install it with the new version from the Gallery or you have it as a cloned repository then just updating to tip). DB migrations will take care of themselves and you don't necessarily have to rebuild the solution as dynamic compilation will compile the new code on the next page load. (That is, unless you have a deployed Orchard site with dynamic compilation disabled.)